# Can I assign domain name to an ec2 instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, godaddy

I have a domain at GoDaddy and my web app running at amazon ec2 instance at port 80. I wanted to use the domain name for the web app. Is it possible to map domain name to ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes, and millions of people have already done this. Do you have a _specific_ question?

Comment: have you tried to create an A record at GoDaddy that points to your EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding an A record in godaddy dns. Which should point to ec2 instace's ip.The ec2 instance should have an elastic ip else it will change whenever the instance restarts and you will have to update the new ip in dns each time the instance restarts inorder to access the web.

For more info you can refer the link below,
https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238